# React native Horizontal Flatlist Animated item Indicator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, flatlist

Hi everyone I try to achieve an effect on an horizontal flatlist in REACT NATIVE.
Actually I have two Flatlist, the top one is Horizontal which contain 9 items like this :

[image]

As you can imagine the flatlist overflow so we don't see all the items so we can scroll with touch event.

I want to when a user click on one of the items the red bottom line move animated under the good item. the black one is a static one indicator.

I use the ScrollToIndex flatlist property to move the item a center of the screen.

I cannot get the right X position to animated the slide active indicator from the previous item to the new one.

the Slider is an Animated.View position as absolute with a translationX transform property.

Does anyone have an example or an explanation for that.

Thank you.

CcHuMi

Comment: you can use .hover CSS on .active element "class" or "id". if you want this red highlighted underline on active element.

Comment: Thanks but I am using react native as mentioned in the tag. I edit my question to specify that in the content.